# How exactly can I unlock Oisten Jägerhorn?

Tags: killing-floor-2

The [wiki page](http://wiki.tripwireinteractive.com/index.php?title=Characters_(Killing_Floor_2)#Community_Newsletter) says

> Liking the Killing Floor 2 [Community Page](http://steamcommunity.com/app/232090/) grants players Oisten Jägerhorn as a playable character.

But that page contains no "liking" interface. I see a "follow", or a "subscribe", that to me are not "liking" the page. Moreover, I have tried both, but the character would not be available when launching the game.

What exactly one has to do to unlock this character?

Comment: If i remember correctly you should subscribe to the community page. If the character should then show up as selectable. If you unsubscribe the character is gone again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the in game advertising for Oisten Jägerhorn has always said "follow."  Not sure why the wiki would say differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to press the "follow" button at the Killing Floor 2 [Community Page](http://steamcommunity.com/app/232090/)

I'd suggest to do this while the game is closed, if that didn't work unfollow and try it again with the game fully launched (albeit it should work with the game closed). If that also didn't work, go to your inventory in the game (while still following the community page), which will refresh all your items every time you go there and then go to gear. Oisten should then appear between all your other playable characters.

And if that didn't work, I'd suggest to write a bug report to Tripwire.